# Catching "Enter Key" works with IE but not Firefox - used in Cognos

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keydown, cognos

I'm using Cognos and I'm trying to catch the <kbd>enter</kbd> key so that the user's input is checked before the prompt is submitted.

Even if you don't have experience in cognos, I would appreciate it if you looked at my code :) It's pretty much a drag and drop program for business reports.

I have a Text Box Prompt on my cognos prompt page and I'm trying to set a 3 char minimum for user input. I have surrounded that Text Box Prompt with a div using HTML Items as shown below.

```
<div onKeyDown="return keyMon(event)"> Cognos Text Box </div>
```

I then have another HTML Item that contains the function `keyMon()`, as shown below:

```
<script>
function keyMon(e3)
{
    var key = e3 || window.event;

    if(key.keyCode == 13){

        var fW = (typeof getFormWarpRequest == "function" ?
        getFormWarpRequest() : document.forms["formWarpRequest"]);
        if ( !fW || fW == undefined) {
            fW = ( formWarpRequest_THIS_ ?
            formWarpRequest_THIS_ : formWarpRequest_NS_ );
        }
    
        var custValue = fW._textEditBoxCustomerPrompt;  

        if(custValue.value.length > 0){
            if(custValue.value.length >= 3){
                promptAction('next'); //Submit the user's input
            }else{
                alert("Please enter a search value that is 3 or more characters long.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

As I said above, this works fine with IE. When it runs in Firefox, it picks up the Enter key, the alert box pops up as it should, but only for a millisecond and then disappears. But it still proceeds to the next page. So obviously the "return false;" isn't doing much.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to put a band-aid on it... Instead of returning false, I cleared out the Parameter Text Box, thus making the prompt not submit. Then I fired the alert.

If anyone has the solution to my original question, please feel free to add it because it's really bugging me.

```
<script>
function keyMon(e3)
{
    var key = e3 || window.event;

    if(key.keyCode == 13){

        var fW = (typeof getFormWarpRequest == "function" ?
        getFormWarpRequest() : document.forms["formWarpRequest"]);
        if ( !fW || fW == undefined) {
            fW = ( formWarpRequest_THIS_ ?
            formWarpRequest_THIS_ : formWarpRequest_NS_ );
        }

        var custValue = fW._textEditBoxCustomerPrompt;  

        if(custValue.value.length > 0){
            if(custValue.value.length >= 3){
                promptAction('next'); //Submit the user's input
            }else{
                //Delaying the alert box so that the user's enter press will not exit the alert box.
                setTimeout("alert('Please enter a search value that is 3 or more characters long.')",250);
                fW._textEditBoxCustomerPrompt.value = "";   
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```